# What are the clues for Fulbright's involvement?

Tags: plot-explanation, beverly-hills-cop-3

I watched *Beverly Hills Cop 3* some days ago and there's something I can't grasp, and I remember having the same problem when I watched that movie 2 decades ago...

How does Foley deduce that Secret Service Agent Steve Fulbright is involved with the counterfeiters? Is there any clue during the movie or is it just a hunch?

Comment: Orrin Sanderson gets shot by Agent Fulbright, and just before Foley says he worked it out Fullbright says I got Sanderson handcuffed in the car. He was in on it right?  I reckon there was some type of scene where foley saw him dead and worked it out based on the comment , but its not a great script and parts were probably cut out that explained it better, and we see that Axel sees?